# Can't load static assets with next.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I use Next.JS to build a small landing page including videos and images. Since the assets are static I assumed the practice here is to create a static folder and the call the videos/images from there.

Somehow Next is not able to find my assets though - how so? When I use them within the `public` directory, it works fine - but I guess this is a bad practice?

```
<img height={320} src="/static/images/hero/tag.svg" alt="" className="float-right" />
<video src="/static/video/hero.mp4" playsInline loop muted autoPlay poster="/static/video/hero-poster.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In nextjs [static file serving](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving) works only from public folder.

You add an image to `public/my-image.svg`, the following code will access the image

```
return <img src="/my-image.svg" alt="my image" />
```

Couple of notes must be taken care:
*Note: Don't name the public directory anything else. The name cannot be changed and is the only directory used to serve static assets.*

*Note: Be sure to not have a static file with the same name as a file in the pages/ directory, as this will result in an error.*

---

Answer (score 1):

Both options has valid use cases

Assets - files are bundled directly into compiled chunks. That mean no extra request to load it in runtime and assets are instantly available. Definitely way to go with icons and other "inline" content. (You need to have appropriate webpack loader each file type. Images are supported out of the box but other file types may need manual config)
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets

Static - oridinary static files served directly by webserver. useful for big files, downloads, rarely accessed files etc.
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/static

In your case I would recommend images to be asset. Video can be static.